# (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' when input video file

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

- Python Version : 3.8.3
- face_recognition version : 4.5.1
- IDE : Jupyter Notebook

#### Description

I'm having problem to run this program, the error under below

[image]

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

When I run this code, the video is played. And when the video ends, that error occurs

Here's my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"D:\JupyterNotebook_DOC\KETI_SL_0000000001.avi")
while(True):
    #capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #Convert the vedeo into BGR video without color
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    #Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    
    #Press Q on keyboard to exit
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
#when everything done, release the videocapture object
cap.release()
#closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Either your path to you video is in error or it cannot be read, so you get no frames to convert to gray. Check your path and that the video is good and whether OpenCV can read AVI format.

Comment: check `ret`!!!!!